# Using Theme.Sherlock.Light, my layout preview is white, but it's gray on physical devices

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, but I'm not using any kind of of other theming. My application looks fine in the layout editor, because I'm using a certain color scheme that goes well with the white background shown. Although, when I run my application on a device 2.x, 3.x or 4.x, I get a very light gray color as the background, but it's definitely not white. Am I missing something? I thought the Light theme was a light gray action bar with a white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sherlock light theme is a copy of Holo.Light, which uses a very light grey as the default background colour.

You can override it to white it you like. In your application theme (create one if you need to which extends Sherlock Light), set the following attribute:

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```